# What is practical purpose for bidirectional override "bdo"?

Tags: html, web-standards

Before coming here, I tried myself by googling. After I read these two links

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_bdo.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_bdo

I still don't understand clearly what is the practical purpose?

Thanks in advance for those who shed some light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty striaghtforward. If you're writing a web page using a default language, such as English, that is rendered left-to-right, and you want to include a island of text in another language, such as a quote in Hebrew, that is rendered right-to-left you can use this tag to override the base direction in which the text is written onto the page in case the bi-directional algorithm is getting it wrong. You need to make sure that the font you're using supports the appropriate character set too, of course.

[http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/struct/dirlang.html](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.2.4)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code bellow, and noticed that it is apparently obsolete for Hebrew, at least:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>If your browser supports bi-directional override (bdo), the next line will be written from right to left (rtl):</p>

<p>חדשות, ידיעות מהארץ והעולם - עיתון הארץ</p>
<bdo dir="rtl">חדשות, ידיעות מהארץ והעולם - עיתון הארץ</bdo>

</body>
</html>
```

Both seemed to output the same line, which confused me, but prompted a search that lead me to the following article:

> The bidirectional ordering of text in AbiWord is done automatically,
>   closely following the Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm (UBA; see the
>   Unicode Consortium website). The Unicode character set assigns each
>   character certain directional properties which are then used by the
>   UBA to order text. Thus, Hebrew or Arabic characters will
>   automatically be treated as right-to-left, and English characters as
>   left-to-right. There are some characters that are directionally
>   ambiguous, and how they are treated by the UBA depends on what
>   characters are found in their vicinity (this includes all white space
>   and punctuation characters).

http://fantasai.tripod.com/qref/HTML4/structure/bdo.html

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks a lot. By the way, asked this question 6 years ago !! Always loves SO

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><p dir="rtl"><bdo>This is a right to left English text</bdo></p><p dir="ltr"><bdo>זהו טקסט עברי משמאל לימין</bdo></p></body></html>